# how to make both the top bar & main bar responsive in one mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, elementor

The problem that I have is with website responsiveness on mobile.

Note that I'm using WordPress & Elementor to build this.

A client asked me to provide a header menu as a top bar & main bar, Bluehost is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Desktop version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRSHz.png
2. Mobile version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QKO4.png

In Elementor, both the top bar & main bar were interpreted as separate nav menus, therefore, on Desktop it was fine, but on mobile there were two hamburger buttons. I'm not sure how can I make both bars shrink in one mobile menu like on Bluehost, can anyone help?

Here are screenshots of my scenario:

1. Desktop version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/37sSJ.png
2. Mobile version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfEY.png

Comment: You can duplicate menu code and set different ID to each menu then duplicate JS click code and set ID's each menu!

Comment: I would suggest you to provide some code for us to better understand your issue and being able to provide you with the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it should be easy.

### On Desktop

Make two menu

- top bar
- main bar

Top bar contains all the stuff which is shown in the desktop image. Main bar contains all the stuff which are there in image + the item on the top bar.
Add CSS to hide them on desktop.

### on Mobile

Make top bar hidden. Turn main bar to hamburger, turn on the display for the items which are from top bar.

> You can also reverse the scenario and have all item on top with hidden main items and show them when on mobile.

Comment: thanks for your help. but how can I exactly display the items from the top bar in the main bar (mobile) while using elementor? how can I do this with custom CSS?

Comment: Create items for those in the main bar. And control it with custom css using `media` . You can read about that here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp